# error: Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because it is writable by group or others

Tags: cron, alpine-linux, logrotate

> error: Ignoring /etc/logrotate.conf because it is writable by group or others

I got this error from my crontab log

`4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           520 Mar 27 12:15 logrotate.conf`

I am given `644` for `logrotate.conf`, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are the perms on your /etc directory?

Comment: 4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root           520 Mar 27 12:15 /etc/logrotate.conf
4 drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Apr  5 05:47 /etc/logrotate.d these are the perms for logrotate

Comment: This error is generally misleading. Since the directive to include any configuration files found in /etc/logrotate.d/ is given in /etc/logrotate.conf, any file permission issues inside the /etc/logrotate.d/ directory are going to be reported as stemming from /etc/logrotate.conf, like we see here. You need to verify a 644 mask on all the configuration files *inside* of /etc/logrotate.d/ as well.

Comment: @parttimeturtle this way only root is able to write to that log file so you are "forced" to run your application with root as well and this can lead to security issues..

How is the application supposed to append data to log files then?

Comment: I answer myself: I were trying to tell logrotate to force rotation over the log file itself while it expects logrotate configuration file as its parameter. Pointing to configuration file it gives this other error which is so self explainatory: «error: skipping "/var/log/foo.log" because [...] **Set "su" directive in config file** to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.»

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give chmod 644 to the file placed in logrotate.d folder.